Relationship Between Zeros of Induced Dirichlet Characters
I was reading the paper "Counting Zeros of Dirichlet L-functions" by Bennett et al and came across the following statement at the end of page 1:

Let $Z(\chi) $:= $\{\rho \in \mathbb{C} : 0 < \beta < 1, L(\rho, \chi) = 0\} $, where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character. If $\chi$ is induced by another character $\chi^*$, then $Z(\chi) = Z(\chi^*) $.

This raised a few questions for me:

Could someone explain why $ Z(\chi) $ and $ Z(\chi^*) $ are equal?
What is the intuition behind this relationship?
Are there specific examples or references that demonstrate how this equality holds in practice?

Any insight or references would be greatly appreciated!

This is a better fit for MSE. From the definitions and the Euler products, the $L$-function of $\chi$ is equal to that of $\chi^$ up to a finite product: $L(s,\chi)=L(s,\chi^)\prod_{p\mid q} (1-\chi^*(p)p^{-s})$ where $q$ is the conductor of $\chi$. (This relation is easily verified for $\Re s >1$, but holds for all $s$ by the uniqueness principle.) Now recall Dirichlet $L$-functions do not vanish on $\Re s =0$.

This has nothing to do with the Dirichlet problem.

@OfirGorodetsky By definition, $Z(\chi)$ and $Z(\chi^)$ lie in the strip $0<\Re s<1$. So the last sentence in your remark should be: "Now observe that $\prod_{p\mid q} (1-\chi^(p)p^{-s})$ has no zeros in the strip $0<\Re s<1$, in fact it only has zeros on the line $\Re s=0$." In addition "conductor of $\chi$ should be modulus of $\chi$". Note that the conductor of $\chi$ is just the modulus of $\chi^*$.

@OfirGorodetsky Thank you very much for answering my question. However, I believe that in the product, we should include the condition $(p \mid q$ and $p \nmid q^$, where $q^$ represents the conductor of $X^*$. I just wanted to clarify this point.

@GHfromMO thanks

@FatimaMajeed The factors corresponding to $p\mid q^$ are equal to $1$, because $\chi^(p)=0$ for such primes. So the restriction $p\nmid q^*$ does not change the product. In short, the product in Ofir Gorodetsky's comment is correct.

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

@GHfromMO Thanks alot

@GHfromMO Thanks for the corrections.
